# Can we have changes related to two different JIRA tickets merged into one merge request in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have 2 JIRA tickets and changes done affect different files.
So if I send a merge request to one person to review, can I add both the commits in one merge request (but the commit history should be shown for both of the tickets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have this in a way by adding the two JIRA ticket numbers in the commit message.
In this way both the tickets will be updated with this commit which includes fix for both the tickets.
And the merge request will be one.

I am not sure if this is a good way but maybe this will be good if you alone are working in that module and no one else does any changes to the files under change